# Comparing sets of overlapping correlations

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, independence, graph-theory

I have a data set of N samples (>10k) and expression measurements for P genes. Among the P genes, there are subsets P<sub>tf</sub> (795  genes) and P<sub>target</sub> (2492 genes) that form a bipartite graph. Not all pairs of genes between the two sets are connected. I want to test if the set of absolute correlations between connected gene pairs (8427 pairs) is greater than those of the unconnected pairs (1972713  pairs).

My first thought was to use a 2 sample t-test or Wilcoxon test to compare the absolute correlations of the connected pairs against a random set of 10000 absolute correlations among the unconnected pairs. I am a little hesitant to do this because there is overlap between the variables I am using to calculate the correlation both within a set and between sets, which sounds like some kind of independence violation. Any suggestions on how to proceed?